# Print preview with custom fonts on multiple devices

Tags: react-native, svg, printing, webfonts

I have an app where we produce physical greeting cards.  The user can compose their cards on any device (phone, tablet, desktop).  We have a react native and web application.  Each card has several different messages with up to 3 different fonts per card.  There are a total of 150 fonts out of all of our designs.

Web fonts are pretty straight forward but I found out the hard way that ios can struggle w/ rendering some fonts correctly when it comes to lineHeights (cutting off text a lot of the time when one is specified).  Our current solution has been to provide line height values for both web and ios which is getting pretty tedious.

One of our other hurdles is trying to figure out how we can render this text uniformly across all devices.

I recently decided to look into SVG, primarily because of the way it allows us to easily scale font sizes based upon it's container (not so easy w/ react native or HTML/CSS).  However I quickly ran into issues where text wrapping is not so easy.

At the end of the day I would ideally like to have one solution that both native apps, web and our print service can use to generate these files.

As of now the only options I can figure are:

- Stick with the current approach and maintain a database of line heights for both ios and web
- Use SVG and create a text wrapping algorithm
- Create a backend service that generates all of our SVG files on the fly.  Seems to provide me what i want with a single solution but network latency when a user types could be a huge bottle neck.

Does anyone have recommendations?